# Query asked for an index in c#, but not in plain SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, indexing

In SQL server, a query executed without any issues and returned around in 2-3 seconds time. But when I run it through C# .net sql connector, to obtain the result to a program, it took around 2-3 minutes to execute. Adding index to the table solved this. Any reason this could happen?

Comment: You can SQL profile it and tell us.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) article.